# What is causality, according to the Scriptures?

Tags: nature-of-god, creation, time, eternity

I often hear that God caused time to exist, or created time.
But causality is relatable to us as a temporal concept, at least in the sense that it requires strict ordering; nothing caused can logically precede its cause (otherwise we could never prove for example that God is Supreme because of His power to cause anything, if causation is meaningless or without order or hierarchy). Time certainly teaches us this and causality is an attribute of time--but perhaps causality is not unique to time? It must be so if time was indeed "caused".
Therefore no definition of "eternal" may ignore causality, eternity itself providing for and always being consistent with causality; causality necessarily transcends "time" as we know it, because "time" as we know it was at least purportedly "caused".

Further compounding the subject is the fact that time is not always a singleton nor is it always referred to with the definite article in Scripture; it may be used in an apparent singleton sense as in Revelation 10:6 ("there should be time no longer"), but in other places the indefinite article is used, "a time", as in [Ecclesiastes 3](https://godrules.net/library/kjvstrongs/kjvstrongsecc3.htm).
Given that there are multiple "times" in God's purview and appointed by Him to His creations, what sense are we to make, Scripturally, from the assertion that God created time, if the causal aspect is discounted? For example there is no verse in any translation I am aware of that states that God "created time" or that He "caused causality to exist", since the latter would require circular definition.
One could purport that God is able to make no sense or have His attributes be circularly defined, but that would make Him unknowable (and void of virtue), contradicting John 17:3.

Therefore what is causality, or eternity for that matter, according to the Scriptures? How do time, eternity and causality relate, according to the Scriptures?
Is there any inherent attribute of time, if causality is not unique to time?

Answer (score 4):

God, himself, is the cause of all things.

There is no 'law of causality' that is greater than God, to which law he is subject.

Else, one would have to abandon the worship of God (God forbid) and one must needs worship this 'law of causality' (let it not be).

The question fails to grasp that God, himself, the eternally existent and uncreated Spirit, is the ever-present, always existent **cause of all else, other than himself.**

The question attempts to give a *concept* an existence of its own. God alone, the ever present Spirit, is, alone, He who is not dependent on anything other than . . . . .  his own existence.

All else, concrete and abstract, takes its existence - **from Him.**

---

> All things came into being through Him, and apart from Him nothing came into being that has come into being. John 1:3 [LSB]

Or, in other words :

> All things were caused to be through him and apart from him was nothing caused to be that was caused to be. [Literally]

God alone is the cause of all else.

It is God who causes all else to happen or to be.

He precedes all else.

For he is eternal.

In the beginning, he was . . . . .  without causation.

Only God has an existence that **depends on nothing other than his own existence.**

---

Exegetical Note :

John 1:3 is preceded by the statement, 'God was the Word'.

Thus, thereafter, one may replace the word 'Word' with the word 'God', for they are equivalent.

Comment: If God had no virtue, He would cease to be God. Therefore there must be a law and a Being who has integrity towards that law for there to be a God who is worthy of worship. And the law must be eternal. Where in the Scriptures do we read that in God there can be no law, or that God is lawless, or is a law unto Himself, without reliable attributes such as integrity, intelligence or virtue?

Comment: The righteousness of God is revealed in the **gospel**. It is not revealed by law. Romans 1:17. _For therein is the righteousness of God revealed_

Comment: The Gospel would be meaningless if law were not real, binding, and to be fulfilled. God sending His Only Begotten Son to fulfill the requirements of the law unto all those with a broken heart and a contrite spirit would be a meaningless charade if God Himself were not bound by any law.

Comment: @pygosceles  The law was honoured in the death of Christ who took law out of the way in his own humanity, in death. We, who believe, are redeemed from the law. And from its curse. I am dead to the law.

Comment: By the law no man is justified, but justification and redemption would be meaningless if the law were mutable.

Comment: Righteousness does not come by law. Righteousness, justification is by the grace of God and is known by a witness within oneself - that one is justified by God himself.

Comment: I am aware of Paul's distinction. Together with all the prophets, he is pointing to the need for a Redeemer because none of us, through our disobedience, can satisfy the demands of the law. But the law remains, otherwise it would be pointless to have a Redeemer who could satisfy the demands of the law. If there were no law, there could be no Redeemer.

Comment: @pygosceles For those in Christ, there is no longer law. It is nailed to the cross _and it is obliterated_. Amen. Now I must cease to comment as the system is encouraging me to discontinue. Regards. My books are all on my website. The website address is on my profile. Adieu.

Comment: Then adultery is OK? That is the logical conclusion of your premise. Moreover there again would be no point to Atonement if there were no law that was broken, that must be satisfied.

Comment: @pygosceles You are no longer arguing with me, sir.. Thus I am not replying. You are arguing with the apostle Paul . . . . . . ..

Comment: Rather with a bunch of interpretations imposed upon Paul that are inconsistent with Scripture, and with reason.

Comment: @pygosceles -  the statutes of the law are eternal because they are the outworking of the immutable character of the eternal God who gave them.  God is bound by his own character, and if we want to know his character we look at the statutes of his law, which can be summarised in (godly) love.  The condemning power of the law is finished for those who are in Christ.  All laws contain a penalty if you break them.. it is this penalty which differs between the Covenant of Works given to Adam, and spelled out by Moses, and the Covenant of Grace.  You shall not commit adultery, if you do the penalty

Comment: @pygosceles - penalty is eternal death under the Law of Works, but discipline under the Covenant of Grace.  There is no eternal condemnation under the Cov. of Grace.  (So King David was disciplined in this world because he was under the Cov. of Grace, but did not lose his salvation.) But the bare statute "You shall not commit adultery", etc, is a reflection of the character of God.. he always keeps it because he cannot not keep it.. it is his character.  That is why the law (the bare statute not including the penalty) is eternal.

Comment: @pygosceles - So under the Cov. of Grace we go back to the statutes of the law to find out how to please God, and to become his image bearers, to try to become more like him.  "All that counts is faith expressing itself through love" (Galatians 5:6).  By faith in the finished work of Christ we enter the Cov. of Grace, by studying his word in both OT and NT we grow in Christlikeness because it contains instruction which is all based on the statutes/law/character of God.

Comment: @AndrewShanks You have a problem with all of this. For Paul teaches that law _as such_ is that to which the believer is _dead_. Not just the penalty. But _law itself_. And how on earth can 'thou shalt not steal/kill/do adultery' _possibly_ express the righteousness and the character of the eternal and almighty Deity - who is _Spirit_ ? You have no scriptures to quote to back up this thesis. Which is why you have quoted none.